# Floppy Disk icon Middle of my screen when game is running

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner in unity and programming, I was following a video for making a Flappy Bird game. Everything works perfectly but when I run the game, I get a floppy disk icon middle of the screen and somehing called DontDestroyOnLoad starts working out of nowhere. I couldn't find or understand anything on google when I search for it. I'm posting the screenshots in case anybody wanna see it.

This icon and dontdestroyonload thing only appears when game is being run:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a little button in the type right of your scene and game view called "Gizmos", un-toggle that button, should fix your issue.
Also don't worry, Gizmos can only be seen in the Unity Editor for level editing and debugging purposes --> if you were to build the game, for instance on IOS, they would disappear.

(if this doesn't fix your issue, then I would just create a new scene and copy your gameobjects over one-by-one)

Comment: To add to this, the gizmo in question is "variables saver"

Answer (score 0):

I see someone responded about the main part of a problem, but I'll clarify about `dontdestroyonload`
`Don't destroy on load` is collection of objects that won't be destroyed when new scene will be loaded, usually objects there come from running them through `DontDestroyOnLoad` method somewhere in a script, however I noticed that some time ago Unity creators started to put there some stuff related to built-in tools (like debug)